# want to scrape all members profile links for member details

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get('http://medicalassociation.in/doctor-search')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

link = soup.find('table',{'class':'tab-gender'})
link1 = link.find('tbody')
link2 = link1.find('tr')[3:4]
link3 = link2.find('a',class_='user-name')
print link3.text
```

Not getting links through this code.I want to take out view profile links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me on several test runs. Just using `requests` and `select` with class selector.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('http://medicalassociation.in/doctor-search')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')    
results = [item['href'] for item in soup.select(".user-name")]
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Request.get()` rendering javascripts and can't see any element.You can use `WebDriver` and get the `page_source` and then fetch the information.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://medicalassociation.in/doctor-search")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a',class_="user-name"):
    if a.text is not None :
       print(a['href'])
```